# Column not found: 1054 Champ 'posts.categorie_id' inconnu

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I want to get POSTS from the CATEGORIE i do the relationship HasMany/belongsTo but it gives me error.

**Categorie.php**

```
public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

**Post.php**

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
```

**SiteController.php**

```
public function getPostsOfCategory($slug){

        $categorie=Categorie::where('slug',$slug)->first();
        $posts= $categorie->posts()->paginate(4);
        $categories=Categorie::all();

        return view('site.blog',['posts'=>$posts,'categories'=>$categories]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you called model `Categorie` but using `Category`.

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
```

->

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Categorie');
```

This might be not the whole solution.

After that check the name of foreign key column in posts table. And change/add it in database or pass as the second parameter to `belongsTo()` relation.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your SiteController

```
public function getPostsOfCategory($slug)
{

        $categorie=Categorie::where('slug',$slug)->first();
        $posts= $categorie->posts;
        $categories=Categorie::all();

        return view('site.blog',['posts'=>$posts,'categories'=>$categories]);

 }
```

Comment: property `->posts` return collection that doesn't have pagination method.

Comment: Right. Missed that. Thanks.

Comment: he doesn't have mistake in controller.